# Generating OSGi bundles distribution with maven-assembly-plugin

Tags: maven, osgi, distribution, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-resources-plugin

I have a multi-module project, where each module is packaged as an OSGi bundle using the Apache Felix maven-bundle-plugin. The whole project is built using a parent POM that lists the above-mentioned modules.  Some modules contain configuration resources (e.g. .properties files) that should not be jarred inside the bundles for deployment but rather externalized in a dedicated config folder.  My goal is to create a distribution folder (possibly, a zip file) that would look something like this:

```
my-app-distribution
    /bundles
        module1-bundle.jar
        module2-bundle.jar
        etc.

    /conf
        external1.properties
        external2.properties
        etc.
```

where the properties files under the `/conf` directory are hand-picked files from the individual modules' `/target` folders. The reason the `.properties` files need to be picked up from the target folders vs. the src folders is that I am using Maven resource filtering, and the *source* property files contain `${..}` placeholders for environment-specific values. Those placeholders are properly resolved during the build process - per build profiles - and the `target/` folders contain actual environment-specific values.

I've done such distribution file manipulations many times - for distributions with executable JARs, etc.  In this case I wanted to use the "moduleSets" configuration of the assembly descriptor - it is easy to pull all binaries/jars into a single distribution folder using moduleSet/binary descriptor. It is also easy to exclude certain files from being packaged into an OSGi bundle - in the maven-bundle-plugin. The only issue I am stuck with is creating the `/conf` distribution folder and collecting the necessary properties files there. I have tried to use "fileSets" inside the "moduleSet/sources" descriptor to include only specific files from `**/target` of each module, but that didn't seem to work.

Anyone have a suggestion/advice?  There's got to be an easy way. Or should I not use  at all?

Thanks,

CV

---

@PetrKozelka I am not sure that extracting configuration files specific to different bundles into a separate module is a good idea. The whole point of OSGi is for bundles to be independent and potentially reusable - both in development and distributions. It only makes sense that - in the source code - the functionality implementation and related configuration files are grouped together.  For a particular distribution though I might need to extract some of the files - if there is a requirement for admins to have control of certain parameters. That may be different for a different distribution/application.  The assembly configuration may change, but the bundles/sources would stay the same. Also, each bundle may potentially be developed and used separately, not all bundles have to always be part of the same uber project - as you seem to assume. What you are suggesting seems to fall into the same old category of packaging enterprise applications by the *type* of artifacts (e.g. "model", "services", "dataaccess", "config" etc.), not by functional domain/features. Such approach works ok within a single application/project, but fails on the enterprise level where there is often a need to reuse subsets of vertical components (split by functional domains).

To your point of being dependent on the file layout in the modules, I agree that there should be no such dependency. Files could be hand-picked by their explicit name or naming convention - per very specific distro requirements. (Which is exactly the case I am facing.)

Comment: it is not a good idea to take files from submodules directly, as it is  prone to errors - especially when you change file layout etc. It's usually better to attach the config as a secondary output artifact, with a specific type and classifier, and then use it as a dependency. In your case, it might perhaps make sense to have one module for processing all the configs, or put it to the distro module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have actually figured out how to do it more or less elegantly. Posting the solution below in case someone else is looking to solve a similar problem.

**SUMMARY**

I am using the `maven-assembly-plugin` to extract the binaries (bundle JARs) from the individual modules and package them in the `<my-distribution-folder>/bundles` directory. In each module where some resource files should be externalized, I consolidate such files under the `/src/main/resources/external` directory, and use `maven-resources-plugin` to copy those resources during the packaging phase to the auto-generated directory in my dedicated `distribution` module that contains the `assembly.xml` descriptor file and is also built as part of the top project. I use `maven-clean-plugin` in the parent POM to clear the contents of the distribution staging directory during the CLEAN phase of the top-level project build.

**MAVEN CONFIGURATION**

Inside each bundle's module POM that contains resources that need to be externalized I add the following resource management configuration:

```
 <build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>

    <!--
    enable resource filtering for resolving ${...} placeholders with environment-specific values 
    exclude any files that must be externalized
    -->
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>external/*.*</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    ...

   <plugins>
        <!-- Copies contents of resources/external to dedicated folder defined by property in parent -->
        <!-- externalized resources will be packaged according to assembly instructions -->
        <plugin>
           <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.6</version>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <id>copy-resources</id>
                   <phase>package</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <configuration>
                       <outputDirectory>
                           ${project.parent.basedir}/${externalizableResourcesStageDir}
                       </outputDirectory>
                       <resources>
                           <resource>
                               <directory>src/main/resources/external</directory>
                               <filtering>true</filtering>
                           </resource>
                       </resources>
                   </configuration>
               </execution>
            </executions>
       </plugin>

        <!-- builds a JAR file for this bundle -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
                    <Export-Package>
                        ${project.groupId}.thismodulepackage*;version=${project.version}
                    </Export-Package>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

where `externalizableResourcesStageDir` is a property defined in the top/parent POM. In the project, I include a special distribution module with the following structure:

```
distribution
   /ext-resources  (target auto-generated dir for external resources from modules)   
   /src
       /assemble
             assembly.xml   (assembly descriptor)
```

The `assembly.xml` file looks like this:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2
      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
<id>bin</id>

<!-- generate a ZIP distribution -->
<formats>
    <format>zip</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<baseDirectory>/</baseDirectory>

<moduleSets>
    <moduleSet>
        <!-- Enable access to all projects in the current multi-module build -->
        <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>

        <!-- select projects to include-->
        <includes>
            <include>myGroupId:myModuleArtifactId1</include>
            <include>myGroupId:myModuleArtifactId2</include>
            ...
        </includes>

        <!-- place bundle jars under /bundles folder in dist directory -->
        <binaries>
            <outputDirectory>${artifactId}/bundles</outputDirectory>
            <unpack>false</unpack>
        </binaries>
    </moduleSet>
</moduleSets>

<!-- now take files from ext-resources in this module and place them into dist /conf subfolder-->
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>ext-resources</directory>
        <outputDirectory>${artifactId}/conf/</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>*</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>

</fileSets>

</assembly>
```

The distribution module's POM would look like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>parentArtifactId</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
</parent>

<groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
<artifactId>distribution</artifactId>
<version>...</version>

<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>Distribution</name>
<description>This module creates the <MyProject> Distribution Assembly</description>
<url>http:...</url>

<!-- NOTE: These dependency declarations are only required to sort this project to the
     end of the line in the multi-module build.
-->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>myModuleArtifactId1</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
 ...
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>dist-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>src/assemble/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

The parent POM would list all the bundle modules, plus the distribution module and also define the assembly plugin:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>myParentId</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        ...

        <!-- directory where build may place any sub-modules' resources that should be externalized -->
        <!-- those resources may be picked up by maven-assembly-plugin and packaged properly for distribution -->
        <externalizableResourcesStageDir>
            esb-distribution/ext-resources
        </externalizableResourcesStageDir>

    </properties>

    <!-- all project modules (OSGi bundles + distribution) -->
    <modules>
        <module>bundle-module1</module>
        <module>bundle-module2</module>
        ...
        <module>distribution</module>
    </modules>



    <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
      ...
      </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--
                Cleans contents of the folder where the externalized resources will be consolidated
                Each module adds its own external files to the distribution directory during its own build
                -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>clean-ext-resources</id>
                            <phase>clean</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <filesets>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>${externalizableResourcesStageDir}</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>*.*</include>
                                </includes>
                                <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                            </fileset>
                        </filesets>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>


                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>src/assemble/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

NOTE: We've also made sure that the externalized resource files are excluded from being packaged inside the individual bundle JARs (see the `resources` section of the module POM.) The resulting unzipped distribution will look like this:

```
my-app-distribution
  /bundles
    module1-bundle.jar
    module2-bundle.jar
    etc.

  /conf
    external1.properties
    external2.properties
    etc.
```